# Printing data from db to ftl page using list and iterator

Tags: java, jdbc, struts2, struts

Is there any way to print only one data from db without using list?

```
public class DisplayPoolAction {

    private List<PoolDescription> data = new ArrayList<PoolDescription>();

    public List<PoolDescription> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String execute() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        DisplayUtilService du = new DisplayUtilService();
        ResultSet rs = du.poolName();

        while (rs.next()) {
            PoolDescription pd = new PoolDescription(rs.getString("POOL_NAME"),
                    rs.getString("QUIZ_ID"));
            data.add(pd);
        }

        if (data.size() > 0)
            return "success";
        return "failure";

    }

}

<#include "../../util/base.ftl">
<@base class='display' scripts=[]  styles=["assets/css/style.css"]>
<section >
<h1>Display Table Information</h1>
<form action="poolnameaction" method="post" charset="UTF-8">
div class="slider">
<table>
<tr>
<td>POOLNAME</td>
</tr>
<@s.iterator value="%{data}">
<tr>
<td>
<s.property value="%{poolName}" />
</td>
</tr>
</@s.iterator>
</table>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</form>
</section>
</@base>
```

I want to display poolnames from db. I have poolnames in db as poolname1, poolname2 etc.

This I am able to display but if I press poolname1. It should go to different page using struts so can you please tell me without using list and iterator how to display?

Comment: Can i print ${rs.getString(1)} in ftl page ????????

Comment: If you don't get data from db then you customize your action to return a result page where you can press text and It will go to different page. It will be good if it also change the url.

Comment: Why you are using ftl instead of jsp? Get only one result and assign it to `PoolDescription` variable, then use `<s:property>` tag to show it.

Comment: My requirement is ftl